# how to count a object as single even if its confidence score is fluctuating in tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, counting, object-detection-api

I am new to the TensorFlow object detection API. I am trying to work out a custom object detection model using the TensorFlow object detection API. Everything is working fine, I want to count the object detected, but it counts the same object multiple times when the confidence score of the object changes.

> Please don't suggest to use object counting API as I have spend lots
>   of time in it.

Comment: isn't there a nms threshold argument somewhere?

Comment: I am using rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config  to train my model what changes I need to do